# Facing issue while assigning values to List or Array in Armstrong No

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int temp;
        int arm, j = 0;
        List<int> armstrongnos = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            arm= 0;
            temp = i;
            while (i > 0)
            {
                arm += (i % 10) * (i % 10) * (i % 10);
                i /= 10;
            }
            if (arm== temp)
            {
                armstrongnos.Add(temp);// OutOfMemory Exception occurs whether you use array or list.
            }
        }
        foreach (var item in armstrongnos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to print armstrong no.s b/w 1 to 1000. In the above code after it is confirmed that it is a armstrong no. I am assigning those values to array or List. But I am having the outofMemory Exception in both the cases. 
Couldn't understand why this issue arise.
Please help to fix the issue. 
What am I doing wrong in this Code. Please explain.

Comment: where is rev declared?

Comment: where does `rev` come from?

Comment: I assume you are using Visual Studio. Have you tried using the built-in debugger to step through the code?

Comment: Sorry instead of rev that should be arm. Typo while editing the code

Comment: @MongZhu after correcting the variable name (and the iterator as mentioned in both answers) the result is `1, 153, 370, 371, 407` in less than a second - seems correct to me then :D.

Comment: @Adwaenyth now it'S working :)

Comment: you could honor the effort of the people who tried to help you by marking one of the answers as accepted. If you don't know how to do it, [here is a description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Good fortune

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running an infinite loop. Your loop's stop conditions are `i < 1000`,
but `i` will **always** be smaller than `1000`  because you are decremating it inside the loop, and `while (i > 0)`, but `i` will **always** be larger than `0`. Running infinitly, your code eventually hits a OutOfMemory Exception.

If you want to play with variable values, **never** do it with the loop's `i` iterator - do it with `temp`.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
{
    arm = 0;
    temp = i;

    while(temp > 0)
    {
       arm += (temp % 10) * (temp % 10) * (temp % 10); 
       temp /= 10;
    }
    if (arm == i)
       armstrongnos.Add(i);
}
foreach (var item in armstrongnos)
    Console.WriteLine(item);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Not the whole story. The crash happens since after the first iteration, `armstrongnos.Add(temp)` is always called.

Comment: @Bathsheba `if (arm == temp)` is never true, since `arm = 0` and `temp = 1` because `i` is `1` at the start of each iteration. neither `arm` nor `temp`change the values. the list is never filled with any values

Comment: @Bathsheba I ran the code. `i` starts with `1` then the while loop dumps it down to `0` then the for loops counts it `++` then the while loop dumps it to 0 then the for loops counts it `++` then the while loop ..... and so on

Comment: @MongZhu: Oops, you're correct. Sorry. Forgot about the `++i` in the `for` loop. That's a drink I owe you.

Comment: `arm` never changes the value, so it will never be equal to `i` because `i` starts at `1`. The List will be empty...

Comment: @MongZhu rev will overflow though... the question is, where is it defined.

Comment: @Adwaenyth `rev` should be `arm`.

Comment: I agree with the infinite loop in the "for", but your second comment of `i > 0` always being true is not correct. He seems to be using int division, which in the case of `/= 10` simply cuts the last digit from the number. Iteratively, you get `1234`, `123`, `12`, `1`, `0`. 0 is achieved once all numbers have been cut off, so it should be achieved for **every** conceivable number (with iteration count = digit count)

Comment: "instead of rev that should be arm. Typo while editing the code" I am cracking up here :D

Comment: @MongZhu Yeah I found that the hard way, before the OP posted.

Comment: @MongZhu then `temp` and `arm` will definitely be the same value once in a while - and while that might take long, it will overflow the list.

Comment: @Bathsheba next time I'll be in London I'll take your offer ;)

Comment: @Bathsheba Count me in? I could use a drink.

Comment: @MongZhu: Perfect. Ping me if you're ever in town.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are modifing your iteration variable.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
{
    // ...
    while (i > 0)
    {
        // ...
        i /= 10;
    }
    // ...
}
```

I've cut out the relevant part. You are always deviding your iteration variable `i` and reassigning it. Thus it will run indefinitely and always add a number to your List until it overflows.

Change `temp` and `i` accordingly and it should work:

```
temp = i;
while(temp > 0)
{
   arm += (temp % 10) * (temp % 10) * (temp % 10);
   temp /= 10;
}
if (arm == i)
{
    armstrongnos.Add(i);
}
```